# In program CSS links for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: css, sublimetext2

I'm currently trying to learn Sublime Text 2, and so far I'm very impressed. But there are some things that I need compared to what I used for editor before (Microsoft Expression Web).

When I had a HTML file and had a class for a div or something. Then I wrote fx:

```
<div class="classname"></div>
```

Then I could CTRL + click on the classname, and it would instantly take me to the CSS file where this class was located, and to the line where it was, and I was able to edit it right away, instead of going into the CSS file and make a search.

Is this possible in Sublime Text 2 as well, or...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, I don't feel the need for such tools, as I check everything in the browser as I go, and with the browser's dev tools, I can see all the CSS that relates to an element and where it is in the style sheet. These days, you can even edit the style sheet in the browser, so it's an amazing code editor in itself. (I use Chrome.)

Comment: @ralph.m - Firebug (and its plugins) can do the same with Firefox...

Comment: Yes, I used Firefox for years, but have moved to Chrome, and much prefer it now. And the native FF dev tools are pretty lousy, too (or at east last time I checked.) It's a real pain using FF now, because I keep clicking Inspect Element instead of Inspect Element with Firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built in feature that does what you require.
But luckily there is a dev who created a plug-in, that does exactly what you want.

Take a look here: [Goto CSS Declaration](https://github.com/rmaksim/Sublime-Text-2-Goto-CSS-Declaration)

Comment: how to install this plugin?

Comment: Install the Package Control Plugin by wbond.

Just go here: https://sublime.wbond.net/installation and follow the install instructions.

Once you are done you can use the Ctrl + Shift + P shortcut in Sublime, type in install and press enter, then search for goto css declaration.

Comment: I installed it, restarted `Sublime Text 2`, hold `Ctrl` button and hover over method names or `.feature` file statements but it didnt show me link. I m using WIN7

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the "Goto CSS Declaration" plug-in, that No Reply linked to in their answer, you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, which let's you jump around in files.

[Unofficial Documentation](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html?highlight=goto%20anything) for more details